# How to do this pandas group by and count functionality?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below and i need to get number of "Not-done" Main tasks and Subtasks grouped by category and Domain. i.e. Groupby Category > Group by Domain > No. of not-done subtasks & No.of undone Main tasks (If any sub task is not-done main task treated as not-done)

Step-1: Count number of Not-done Subs_Task under each Category and Domain?

Step-2: I want to count no.of Not-done Main tasks under each Category and Domain? Means Sub_tasks are Belongs to Main_Tasks..?? if any of it's sub_tasks not-done then main task is treated as not-done.

```
 df.groupby(['Category','Domain','Main_Task']).count()
```

Is giving count i want to find results too

```
  Category   Main_Task    Sub_Task    Domain    Result
0    A        Main_Task1    Sub_Task1     CC      Done
1    A        Main_Task1    Sub_Task2     AB      Not-Done
2    A        Main_Task2    Sub_Task3     AB      Done
3    A        Main_Task2    Sub_Task4     DD      Not-Done
4    B        Main_Task3    Sub_Task5     SC      Done
5    B        Main_Task3    Sub_Task6     CD      Not-Done
6    B        Main_Task5    Sub_Task7     PD      Done
7    B        Main_Task5    Sub_Task8     CC      Not-Done
8    A        Main_Task1    Sub_Task9     PD      Done
9    B        Main_Task3    Sub_Task10    CC      Done
```

Any Effective Solutions??

Comment: You mean `df.groupby(['Category','Domain'])['Result'].count()`

Comment: Nope.. Please find edited question

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and also the desired result, also it should be 1 problem per question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for result not done filter the dataframe:

```
notdone_df = df[df['Result'] == "Not-Done"]
```

Ans for Step 1:

```
notdone_df.groupby(['Category', 'Domain', 'Sub_Task'])['Result'].count()
```

Ans for Step 2:

```
not_done[['Category', 'Domain', 'Maintask']].drop_duplicates().groupby(['Category', 'Domain']).count()
```

I think this will solve your problem.

without droping duplicates also you can do it with groupby.